# Why have some questions I've flagged not been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have flagged questions for moderator attention to delete them, but still I didn't get any response. Even my friend has old ID then me on stackoverflow and the same thing happen to him. So is there any time limit to delete the question if not then moderator should have to response for that?

Comment: Flagging a question for deletion does not guarantee that a question will be deleted. The moderator who examines your flag still gets to make the decision whether or not to delete. Moderators can mark your flag valid (indicating that it has merit), even if they choose not to take action on your flag. They are not obligated to respond to your flag in any other way.  There is no time limit for acting on moderator flags, although they usually get looked at within 24 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you visit your [Flagging Summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/709458)<sup>*</sup> you can find a list of the dispositions for your flags and whether or not they were deemed valid, invalid, disputed, or if they are awaiting review.

[image: Flagging Summary]

<sub>* You can get to your flagging summary page by clicking on your user name, then clicking on your flag weight.</sub>

Comment: If they are valid then what it mean and what if they are invalid?

Comment: Valid means a moderator agreed with your flag. Invalid means they disagreed. Disputed means other flaggers disagreed.

Comment: So can we re-flagged the same question.

Comment: If it was deemed Valid then a moderator will have taken the appropriate action, *but it may not be what you wanted to happen*. If they deemed it Invalid, it likely won't get acted upon. However, if you strongly feel a certain question or answer needs attention yet a moderator has disagreed, you can post a link to the question/answer on Meta and ask for information as to why things happened like they did.

Comment: Current wording as-of today is "Helpful" and "Declined" (instead of Valid and Invalid)